# Получение юникода строки Python

Tags: python, unicode

Всем привет. В чем сам сабж

На входе есть строка вида

```
test = 'qwerty'
```

Необходимо получить вывод вида:

\u0071\u0077\u0065\u0072\u0074\u0079

То есть, юникод каждого символа. Не обязательно через бэкслэш. Может кто знает как это реализовать? Может есть какие-то библиотеки или стандартные методы? Гугл особо ничем не помог

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-to-unicode-characters/

Comment: Благодарю. Статья помогла

Answer (score 2):

```
test = 'qwerty'
print(''.join([f'\\u{b:04X}' for b in test.encode('UTF-8')]))
```

```
\u0071\u0077\u0065\u0072\u0074\u0079
```

Comment: Благодарю. Метод рабочий, но только для латинницы. Мой косяк, нужно было уточнить что работаю со всеми алфавитами

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один вариант, хотя почти такой же:

```
test = 'qwerty'
print(''.join(f'\\u{ord(ch):04x}' for ch in test))
```